# Assigning a window handle from a literal value

Tags: c#, winforms

For a c# program to hide the window of another running program.
the logic is

```
foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (proc.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith("Some_title"))
                {
                    handle = proc.MainWindowHandle;
             } 
            }...
...
SetWindowPos(handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0001 | 0x0002 | 0x0004 | 0x0010 | 0x0080);
...
//later to unhide
 SetWindowPos(handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0001 | 0x0002 | 0x0004 | 0x0040);
```

now if i terminate the program before unhiding the window, i lose the handle of the window which i set to hide. Iterating again through the process list will not get me the hidden window's handle again, since(probably) the hidden window is not the main window anymore for that process. [and it is a chat client with multiple windows]

any method that you can think of, to save  the window handle to a file between invocations of the program , and to do the unhiding at a later point?

i have tried, but literals cannot be assigned back to IntPtr type for using as the handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int literal = 10;
IntPtr handle = new IntPtr(literal);
```

doesnt serve your needs?